# Failed to resolve import "XXX" from "src\App.tsx"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am migrating my project from JS to TS and also from CRA to Vite. Firstly I migrated from JS to TS and then when I tried to run my project locally via `npm run start` i get an error.

**Problem**

`Failed to resolve import "components/Card/Card" from "src\App.tsx".`

Inside `.tsx` and `.ts` files imports are resolved, but Vite cannot resolve them. I get the same error for every import with an absolute name, e.g:

```
import Card from 'components/Card/Card';
import useSounds from 'hooks/useSounds';
import shuffleSound from 'assets/sounds/shuffle.mp3';
```

Changing path to `./components/Card/Card` resolves my issue by I need those imports to be like shown previously (without adding `./` at the start).

**Files**

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "*": ["src/*"],
      },
      "outDir": "./",
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "target": "ESNext",      
      "types": ["vite/client", "vite-plugin-svgr/client", "node"],
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom", 
      "dom.iterable", 
      "es5"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "types/"
    ],
    "include": [
      "src",
      "types"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "dist"
    ]
}
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), svgrPlugin()], 
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    open: false,
  },
});
```

`vite-env.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "memory-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.1",
    "vite": "^4.0.4",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^2.4.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

**Folder sctructure**

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzbdA.png)

**Path to Card component**

[image: card]

I tried many different combinations of `baseUrl, lib, include` options in tsconfig and some options in vite.config.ts

Comment: Could you provide directory structure with `component` opened?

Comment: sure, added new image

Comment: Why don't you use `./`?

Comment: have you found a solution, i have the same error, also with typescript and vite and i cant find any solutions online

Answer (score 1):

This config is working on my side. You should try:

tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  }
```

and in vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: "/src",
    },
  },
});
```

and then:
import Button from src/Button